# Get next/previous record in Collection by Date in Rails (and handle multiple dates on the same day)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm having trouble trying to isolate the next/previous record in a collection. I'm self-taught and relatively new to Rails/coding.

I have a Goal class which has many GoalTasks.

GoalTask has taskduedate. I want to be able to cycle next/previous on the goal_tasks, based on their taskduedate.

The issue is that a task due date is just when the task is due to be completed, but it can be set at any time and may not be in sequential order so that I don't know what else to order it by to correctly cycle through it.

I have created an array of goal_tasks to identify which one is currently being viewed (e.g. Task: 3/20), so I could use that to go to the next one, I think there might be a solution here, but it feels wrong to handle it in the view/controller?

I've tried the below solution from stackoverflow, but it doesn't handle the fact that I have multiple goal_tasks due on the same day, if I click next it just goes to the next day that goal_tasks are due. e.g. if I have three tasks due today and I'm on the first one and click next, it will just skip over the other two for today.

I then tried to add the >= (displayed below) to try and pull the next task (including those on the same day), and I've tried to ignore the current task by doing where created_at is not the same as the current goal_task and where.not, but I haven't managed to successfully get it to cycle the way I want it to, and I imagine there's a better solution.

GoalTasksController:

```
 def show
   @all_tasks_ordered_due_date_desc = @goal.goal_tasks.order('taskduedate ASC', 'id ASC')
 end
```

show.html.erb:

```
Task: <%= @all_tasks_ordered_due_date_desc.find_index(@goal_task) +1 %> /      
<%= @goal.goal_tasks.count%>
```

GoalTask.rb

```
scope :next_task, lambda {|taskduedate| where('taskduedate >= ?', taskduedate).order('id ASC') } 
scope :last_task, lambda {|taskduedate| where('taskduedate <= ?', taskduedate).order('id DESC') } 

  def next_goal_task
    goal.goal_tasks.next_task(self.taskduedate).first
  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the method found here: [Rails 5: ActiveRecord collection index_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490650/rails-5-activerecord-collection-index-by)

Which meant adding a default scope and changing GoalTask.rb to:

```
  default_scope { order('taskduedate ASC') }

  def next_goal_task
    index = goal.goal_tasks.index self
    goal.goal_tasks[index + 1]
  end

  def last_goal_task
    index = goal.goal_tasks.index self
    goal.goal_tasks[index -1]
  end
```